# Importing Libraries on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, user32

Ok, so I'm feeling like a complete idiot, but what I'm trying to do is run some code I found on the internet. The actual code isn't the problem it's this:

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to try to make a C++ program, and this code has the function "FindWindow(some parameters)" among some others. At the top it imports windows.h. Visual Studio, however, tells me that the identifier "FindWindow" is undefined. So I look it up: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

Requirements: Winuser.h (include Windows.h)

Library: User32.lib

DLL: User32.dll

So, first thing I tried was importing winuser.h as well (not that it seems to be saying I need to, but it was worth a shot). No good. So, I look into this User32.dll thing. I'm told that you can't add the .dll itself, you add the .lib, so I turn my attention to that. I have no idea what to do with this, but what I found said various things like "You don't have to worry about this, VS will link it for you" or "You have to add it to dependencies (through project properties -> linker -> blah blah)" or "use this: #pragma comment (lib, "User32")". I tried them all as instructed, but they didn't seem to work. My best guess is I didn't do adding it to dependencies correctly.

My question, then, is what am I doing wrong, and how can I get Visual Studio to recognize FindWindow as existing?

If it helps, here's what the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    HWND p = FindWindow("ProgMan", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And "FindWindow" has a red squiggly line under it, mousing over says "Error: identifier "FindWindow" is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify minimum Windows version for your application. Add these lines before including `windows.h`

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#define WINVER 0x0500
```

Comment: Is this it? Or in addition to adding it to dependencies, or adding the pragma comment, or anything else? I've undone those, because I didn't want extra unnecessary stuff sitting around potentially causing problems. Just adding those lines didn't help.

Comment: Doesn't he need the define for Unicode or ANSI?  FindWindow doesn't exist as a function - the function is findWindowA or FindWindowW and FindWindow is a macro defined to point to one of those based on the Unicode setting

Comment: Actually I might be wrong about that.  If the UNICODE define doesn't exist it should default to the functions ending in A....